# Unable to load simple page in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin.Forms with a portable project. Inside the portable project, I'm trying to download a web page using the following:

```
public static List<Lesson> ReadCurrentLessons()
{
  var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(timetablePage));
  request.ContentType = "text/html";
  request.Method = "GET";
  var z = request.BeginGetResponse((IAsyncResult ar) =>
  {
    var rq = (HttpWebRequest) ar.AsyncState;
    using (var resp = (HttpWebResponse) rq.EndGetResponse(ar))
    {
      var s = resp.GetResponseStream();
    }
  }, null);
  return null;
}
```

Unfortunately, whatever I do, it doesn't work: either the debugger doesn't let me into the first lambda or, if it does, `ar.AsyncState` is always shown being equal to `null`.

What am I doing wrong? I have set the `INTERNET` permission and have verified that the Android emulator has internet access.

Comment: Interestingly enough, this works in neither WP8 nor in Android.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this, from the Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http, and its working great

```
  using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            Task<string> contentsTask = httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri); 

            // await! control returns to the caller and the task continues to run on another thread
            string contents = await contentsTask;
            vendors = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyObject>>(contents);
        }
```

Comment: Interesting, I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Ah I see...I have edited the answer accordingly. I have tested this on a basic HTTP GET and it works in both examples provided. The examples below show the code within a Button click event but I am sure you get the intention..

**Option 1**

Use a delegate method callback e.g.

```
button.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(@"http://www.google.co.uk"));
    request.ContentType = "text/html";
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(this.FinishWebRequest),request);
};

private void FinishWebRequest(IAsyncResult result)
{
    HttpWebResponse response = (result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest).EndGetResponse(result) as HttpWebResponse;
}
```

**Option 2**

Handle the callback inline:

```
button2.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(@"http://www.google.co.uk"));
    request.ContentType = "text/html";
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback((IAsyncResult ar)=>{
        HttpWebResponse response = (ar.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest).EndGetResponse(ar) as HttpWebResponse;
    }),request);
};
```

I have nothing available to test the responseStream functionality but the above code will get you the response you need.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cannot write `await var z`. Also, says here `IAsyncResult` is not awaitable.

Comment: well that doesn't work either. `IAsyncResult` is not awaitable.